# Need to dynamically change position for button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Maybe someone can help me with my application.

I have a square and 4 buttons (plus row, minus row, plus column, minus column).
[Square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBuHY.png)

What I need now for " left minus button (row)" - when mouse are located on second row minus button should be near second row, if first row - near first row, etc.

My solution for now bellow

```js
function changeVposition(move) {
        var top = move.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var bottom = move.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;        
        var minusRow = document.getElementById("deleteRow");
        minusRow.style.position = "absolute";
        minusRow.style.top = (top) + 'px';
        minusRow.style.bottom = (bottom) + 'px';
   }
```

Here I took from each `<tr>` element coordinates (top and bottom)

`<tr onmousemove="changeVposition(this)">` and gave them to my button.

But when I try to add some rows behavior was changed and it is unpredictably.

[one more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPO8r.png)

the css for button and all page is bellow:

```css
* {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

}


table {
  border: 1px solid #00A1D4;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}

.cell {
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  background-color:#00A1D4;
  
}

.cell:hover {
  background-color:#4B496E;
}


#appendCol {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #FFBA5C;
  border: none;
  background-image: url("plus.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  top: 3px;
  right: -84px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;

}

#appendRow {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #FFBA5C;
  border: none;
  background-image: url("plus.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  bottom: -84px;
  left: 3px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;

}




#deleteRow {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #881013;
  border: none;
  background-image: url("minus.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  left: -84px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0; 
  position: absolute;
}

#deleteCol {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #881013;
  border: none;
  background-image: url("minus.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  top: -84px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

}
```

Comment: If you generate the HTML, than you can have buttons for every div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function changeVposition(move) {
        var top = move.offsetTop;      
        var minusRow =           document.getElementById("deleteRow");
        minusRow.style.position = "absolute";
        minusRow.style.top = (top) + 'px';
    
        
    }
```

I found the solution, use   `offsetTop` instead `getBoundingClientRect().top`